# image type validation php

Tags: php, image, validation, types

its all working in my form but image validation isnt working. I just want a script for image type validation. This what I have right now but isnt working and I dont understand why..

```
enter code here

            if( $_FILES['imagem']['error'] > 0){
                $flag_error=true;        
                $errors['imagens'][0]=true;
            }

            if ($_FILES["imagem"]["size"] > 10000000) {
                $flag_error=true;        
                $errors['tamanhoimagem'][0]=true;
            }

            if($_FILES['imagem']['type']!='image/png' || 'image/jpg') {
                $flag_error=true;        
                $errors['tipodeficheiro'][0]=true;

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so trivial.

```
if($_FILES['imagem']['type'] !== 'image/png' && $_FILES['imagem']['type'] !== 'image/jpeg')
```

or better:

```
if(!in_array($_FILES['imagem']['type'], array('image/png', 'image/jpeg')))
```

---

your code doesn't work because the expression is evaluated as `($_FILES['imagem']['type']!='image/png') || 'image/jpg'`.

`||` is a [boolean operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), and the string `'image/jpg'` is [converted to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) `true` by the compiler. Thus, the result of the whole expression is always `true`.

---

Besides, the mime type for JPEG images is `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`.

Comment: if(($_FILES['imagem']['type'] != 'image/png') && ($_FILES['imagem']['type'] !=  'image/jpg')) {
                $flag_error=true;        
                $errors['tipodeficheiro'][0]=true;

                }

Comment: I got this and still not working, says the file is not supported :/

Comment: Maybe it should be `image/jpeg` (note the `e` in `jpeg`)?

Comment: Thank you so much man! I have a lot of time wasted trying to solve errors on this page, this one is the last! really apreciate this helpful site. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this-

```
if(($_FILES['imagem']['type'] != 'image/png') && ($_FILES['imagem']['type'] !=  'image/jpg')) {
                $flag_error=true;        
                $errors['tipodeficheiro'][0]=true;

                }
```